# DES Encryption from C# to PHP not working as expected

Tags: c#, php, encryption, mcrypt, des

I have to recreate things from c# to php.
I dont really know what to do cuz I never really had to deal with things like encryption or something.

In c# I got this:

```
public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        des.Key = key;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        return des.CreateDecryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
    {
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        des.Key = key;
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        return des.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

public static byte[] get8byte(string input)
    {
        byte[] ByteArray = new byte[8];
        string tmp = string.Empty;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            tmp = "" + input[i];
            tmp = tmp + input[i + 1];
            ByteArray[j] = byte.Parse(tmp, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            j++;
            i++;
        }
        return ByteArray;
    }
```

and the key i have to use is encrypted like the following:

```
var Buffer = new char[16];
var cMasterKey = new byte[8];
byte[] Key = {
       (byte) '1', (byte) '2', (byte) '3', (byte) '4', (byte) '5',
       (byte) '6', (byte) '7', (byte) '8'
}; 
cMasterKey = DESUtils.get8byte(new string(Buffer));
MasterKey = DESUtils.decrypt(cMasterKey, Key);
```

The "Buffer" comes from an USB Drive which has a File on it which contains a Masterkey of 16 Chars.
I really don't know how to realize it in PHP. I tried a lot of things like pack('C*', $var) and things like that but I didnt get the same result.
Is there anyone here who knows how to handle it? I dont know if I'm on the right way but I tried things like this:

```
$key = pack('C*', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
$masterbyte = pack('C*', $buffer);
$decmasterkey = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $key, $masterbyte, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

Comment: Consider accepting answers that are helpful. 

To accept an answer click on the hollow checkmark next to the answer that is best, doing so will increase your reputation and allow more capabilities, See [reputation faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)  See [this page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`'1'` in C# is a character literal. Characters can be directly cast to a byte under the default ASCII assumption. So `'1'` is actually a 0x31 byte and not a 0x01 byte like you have in PHP.

You "want":

```
$key = "12345678";
```

Whether the decoding of `$buffer` is correct depends on its content and how you read it.

---

Some notes:

- **Don't use DES nowadays.** It's really insecure. AES is a better alternative.
- **Never use [ECB mode](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Comment: At first. Thanks for your response. I know DES is insecure but I'm not able to change it because its used in a production system like that. The same for ECB. So $key = "12345678" is the equivalent to c#'s "bytething" i wrote in the question?

Comment: @Goneja So security is not a priority, interesting in this day and age. I hope you let your users know that the security is poor.

Comment: Dude, theres a little more behind it then just changing 1 encryption method in 1 little php script.

Comment: That is what programmers are paid for. So, would you accept that excuse from your bank?

Comment: *"So $key = "12345678" is the equivalent to c#'s "bytething" i wrote in the question?"* - Yes. Did it work or are there other problems?

Comment: Its not working as expected. I cant figure out how to recreate the get8bit() Function.

Comment: I don't see a `get8bit` method anywhere.

Comment: I now tried like the following:
`function get8bit($input) {
$byte = array();
 $j = 0;
 for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++)
 {
  $tmp = "" . $input[$i];
  $tmp = $tmp . $input[$i + 1];
  $byte[$j] = unpack('C*', $tmp);
  $j++;
  $i++;
 }
 $byte = pack('C*', $byte);
 return $byte;
}`

Comment: First of all, please take more care about your code. I see a `get8byte` in your Java code, but you're talking about `get8bit` for some reason, which leads me to believe that those are different functions. Now, that method is a simple Hex to Binary decoder method. PHP includes `hex2bin` which does the same thing, so you don't have to implement your own.